Total least squares for 3 data points in 2D
I am looking through some old code of mine, and I have the following procedure to calculate the best line fit in 2D for three points $(x_1, y_1)$, $(x_2, y_2)$, and $(x_3, y_3)$:

Calculate $(\bar{x}, \bar{y})$:
$$
   \bar{x} = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3}{3}
   $$
$$
   \bar{y} = \frac{y_1 + y_2 + y_3}{3}
   $$

Compute the following sums:
$$
   S_{xx} = \sum_{i=1}^3 (x_i - \bar{x})^2
   $$
$$
   S_{xy} = \sum_{i=1}^3 (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})
   $$
$$
   S_{yy} = \sum_{i=1}^3 (y_i - \bar{y})^2
   $$

Finally the slope is given by
$$
   m = \frac{S_{yy} - S_{xx} + \sqrt{(S_{yy} - S_{xx})^2 + 4 S_{xy}^2}}{2 S_{xy}}
   $$
and the intercept is given by
$$
   b = \bar{y} - m \bar{x}
   $$


I am struggling to find a name/reference/proof for this method. Can someone share one with me?

those slope and intercept obtained are called OLS estimator if you are econometrics student

Look for Deming-Regression.
The formula you show is for the special case when errors in $x$ and $y$ are estimated to be about the same, thus the perpendicular distance from $(x_i, y_i)$ to the line of best fit are squared and their sum minimised.
In case you are interested in some examples and programs for several HP pocket calculators, I once prepared an article about this subject and how CAS may help to find the formulas.
